# A word for being aroused, pleased, and excited by an abstract idea

Tags: single-word-requests

There's a particular flavor of pleasure that leads to obsessively geeky behavior. One example might be poring over a book of baseball statistics, another might be coding up a minimax tree pruning algorithm just for the fun of it.

Is there a word for this particular thing?

Edit: The closest word I can think of is **gratification** or **gratified**, but it captures neither the fact that conception of an idea can be rewarding by itself, nor the compulsive intensity of the feeling. **Addiction**/**addicted** might work if it emphasized pleasure more than behavior. **Compulsion**/**compelled** might also work except it doesn't necessarily imply euphoria at all.

**Passion**/**passionate** seems to connote an ongoing focused interest in an object, or a class of ideas or activities. The word I'm looking for would refer to an immediate sensation, like **happy**, **despondent**, or **bemused**.

Edit: **Enthralled** is quite close except I think it connotes a lack of motivation.

I've thought of closer words: **stimulated** and **inspired**. They're not quite right either because they still don't emphasize euphoria.

Edit: **OK check this out.** There's a term "ideas as opiates", which expresses my thoughts exactly. I don't know its origin. There's a song by Tears for Fears with that name but I know they got a lot of their ideas from philosophical readings. Anyway, is there a word that means, "high on an idea as if it were an opiate"?

Edit: That term says what I mean only coincidentally. It's based on Marx's writings and doesn't use **opiate** the same way I do. I'm not talking about using an idea to self-medicate. I'm talking about being euphorically "intoxicated", so to speak.

Edit: Are **captivated** etc feelings? They're states of being but I don't think they're feelings. Or am I wrong?

Comment: .....passion?......

Comment: entranced or spellbound possibly? Or you can be absorbed in a book or statistics. Or obsessed!

Comment: How about "enthralled"?

Comment: engrossed?  Sucked in?  Captivated?  As in, I picked up an undergraduate text on string theory, and (was sucked in) (was captivated) (became engrossed).

Comment: I was thinking of "mesmerized" which has the "opiate" sort of effect, but it is most commonly used for a visual sort of stimulus rather than engrossment with a subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Engrossed, enwrapped, hooked, addicted, obsessed, manic, crazed, consumed, captivated, absorbed, psyched, stoked. And if there's not already a word for it, try making a new one.

Comment: I think I'll have to make a new one.

Answer (score 1):

> [titillate](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/titillate)
>
> verb
> [intransitive, transitive] (often disapproving)Verb Forms
>
> to interest or excite somebody, especially in a sexual way

Note the "especially", which means it doesn't have to mean a sort of sexual thrill but does hold that possibility.

Seems a really good fit to "aroused, pleased, or excited". It doesn't signify anything regarding the nature of the source, though. (juicy gossip, a strip tease, or an interesting puzzle?) Can't think of anything that contains that particular aspect, as well.